# How to write Rewrite rule for same path using Rewrite API?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have two paths,

http://example.com/test/abc -> This is subpage

http://example.com/test/xyz -> This will be taxonomy link

I tried adding following rule, did flush and all.

```
add_rewrite_rule('^test/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?test_taxonomy=$matches[1]', 'bottom');
```

when I put bottom in the after parameter, The taxonomy link does not work and when I put top, the page link does not work. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Do you only want to rewrite `/text/xyz` or do you want to rewrite all `^test/([^/]*)/?` ? What page link doesn't work?

Comment: I want to rewrite all as there will be other terms as well in that taxonomy.